# Ошибки в интернет-магазине

Tags: php, веб-программирование, opencart

Добрый день. Установил на сайте OpenCart, но на сайте показывается огромное количество ошибок и с кодировкой проблемы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне делать? Вот магазин - http://fishing-trade.com/

Comment: Настроить и исправить.... или свернуть это гиблое дело и нанять того кто исправит) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да у вас не только с кодировкой проблемы, судя по всему, а еще и права выставлены неверно или вообще не выставлены)

Answer (score 0):

все отлично работает...

**а как вообще сам движок?**
кто в курсе?

слышал что грамотный

Если сравнивать с [simpla](http://simplacms.ru/)

OpenCart лучше или нет???

Comment: со своей проблемой разобрылся уже, спасибо.

движок мне очень понравился, все автоматизировано, интуитивно понятно